# Issue with JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, go

I'm fairly new with working with Golang and I came across an issue when trying to send back a JSON response.

My main.go code looks something like this:

```
import (
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/justinas/alice"
) 

mx.Handle("/verify", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(controller.VerifyHandler)).Methods("GET").Name("verify") // Used to display verify.html
mx.Handle("/verify", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(verifyUser)).Methods("GET") // I'm actually not certain if I can call 2 different function handlers on the same URL
```

My verifyHandler calls RenderTemplates, which looks something like this:

```
func RenderTemplates(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, name string) {
    f, err := os.Open("./templates/" + name)
    check(err)
    defer f.Close()
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    check(err)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(buf))
}
```

RenderTemplates is used to display my verify.html page

Then I have the verifyUser function handler which sends back a JSON formatted response, which looks something like this:

```
response := generateResponse("Message goes here", false)
            res, err := json.Marshal(response)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.Write(res)
```

Then I have my AngularJS controller to make the request:

```
app.controller("verifyControl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: "/verify"
      }).success(function(data) {
       $scope.message = data.msg;
       console.log(data);

    });

  }]);
```

The issue is the response that I get back from my AngularJS call is not JSON, instead it's the verify.html HTML page, which I assume came from verifyHandler. Is there a solution where I can get the JSON response?

Comment: What does the `.Name()` function do? Is this part of Gorilla mux? Could not find documentation on it

Comment: Yes, it's part of Gorilla mux. It can be found [here](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.Name)

Comment: If my understanding is clear, you need 2 path for that (or different http-method), one for returning your template, another for raw-json.

Comment: @mission.liao How should I go about doing that? Which path should I point to for my JSON response?

Comment: Your routes are matched top-down, so the JSON handler never gets called because `/verify` is already matched. You can either change the route to something else - like `/verify.json` or have a single route and look at the client's `Accept-Encoding` header. If they send a header strictly with `application/json` serve JSON.